# can write to Excel cell but cannot read

Tags: excel, vb.net

Using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2022, I can write to an Excel cell but I can't read from it. Even after providing the row and column numbers, it still thinks it is returning a Range.

In the following code, writing to the cell works. You can see the new value if you put a watch on it.

```
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelWBs As Excel.Workbooks
Dim ExcelWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExcelWS As Excel.Worksheet
ExcelWBs = ExcelApp.Workbooks
ExcelWB = ExcelWBs.Add
ExcelWS = ExcelWB.Sheets.Add
ExcelWS.Cells(1, 1) = "qwerty"
```

However, trying to read the cell throws an exception.

> "ExcelWS.Cells(1, 1).Value2" gives the message "Public member 'Value2' on type 'Range' not found."

I get the same exception if I try `ExcelWS.Cells(1, 1).Value2` in immediate mode. Furthermore, autocomplete doesn’t show a `Value2` member (but the watch does). And `debug.print(ExcelWS.Cells(1, 1)` gives.

> Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid.

Why don't the indices turn the Range object into a scalar on a read, while they work on a write (or in a watch)?